# Correctly provisioning the graph data science plugin on grapheneDB

Tags: neo4j, graphenedb, graph-data-science

I have a graph working fully with the plugin locally in neo4j desktop. I've replicated everything from this graph in my grapheneDB instance. I can't use the gds procedures as I get the error:

```
gds.proc... is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals.
```

I know to fix this I need to add these two lines to the config/properties file:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*,gds.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*,gds.*
```

I just dont know how to do that on grapheneDB, I've read all the docs I can find.

I've tried adding the gds plugin by adding the jar file as just a stored procedure and then also  as a server extension with a zip file containing both the jar file and the two config lines mention above in a neo4j-server.properties file.

When added as a server extension I can tell neo4j hasnt found the gds plugin at all. Am I just missing a location in the properties file? Or am I missing something obvious in the stored procedure upload method?

Using the dev free tier graphenedb, Neo4j Community Edition 3.5.17 and graph data science 1.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of weeks back and forth with graphene support, the config changes have been made. They will be adding support for the GDS plugin as part of their base image soon, but until then you may still need to request that they patch your db for you and add it as a stored procedure.